# No uniform with name in shader exclusively on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, raspberry-pi

Similar Questions:
[No uniform with name in shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754594/no-uniform-with-name-in-shader) ,
[Fragment shader: No uniform with name in shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424701/fragment-shader-no-uniform-with-name-in-shader)

LibGDX: libgdx.badlogicgames.com

LibOnPi: www.habitualcoder.com/?page_id=257

I am attempting to run LibGDX on a Raspberry Pi with little luck. After some trial and error I eventually got it to start throwing the error "no uniform with name 'mvp' in shader". The problem is much like the similar questions, however in my situation it seems to me that 'mvp' is actually being used by the shader to set the positions.

The really strange part is that it runs on the PC (Windows 7 x64 in Eclipse ADT) just fine, but not on the Pi. Does the pi handle shaders differently, if not, what is causing this error to be thrown exclusively on the pi?

```
Vertex_Shader = 
    "attribute vec3 a_position; \n"
  + "attribute vec4 a_color; \n"
  + "attribute vec2 a_texCoords; \n"
  + "uniform mat4 mvp; \n"
  + "varying vec4 v_color; \n" + "varying vec2 tCoord; \n" 
  + "void main() { \n" 
  + "   v_color = a_color; \n"
  + "   tCoord = a_texCoords; \n"
  + "   gl_Position =  mvp * vec4(a_position, 1f);  \n"
  + "}";

Fragment_Shader = 
    "precision mediump float; \n"
  + "uniform sampler2D u_texture; \n"
  + "uniform int texture_Enabled; \n"
  + "varying vec4 v_color; \n"
  + "varying vec2 tCoord; \n"
  + "void main() { \n"
  + "   vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, tCoord); \n"
  + "   gl_FragColor = ((texture_Enabled == 1)?texColor:v_color); \n"
  + "}";
...
shader = new ShaderProgram(Vertex_Shader, Fragment_Shader);
...
shader.setUniformMatrix("mvp", camera.combined);
```

I also noticed this question:
[c++ OpenGL glGetUniformLocation for Sampler2D returns -1 on Raspberry PI but works on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364010/c-opengl-glgetuniformlocation-for-sampler2d-returns-1-on-raspberry-pi-but-wor)
which is quite similar, however implementing the proposed solution of putting the "#version 150" at the top of the shader just broke it on the PC too. (stated that there was no uniform with name 'mvp')

EDIT:

1 - Added Fragment Shader at request of keaukraine

2 - Fix found by Keaukraine and ArttuPeltonen. Raspberry Pi requires a version number in the shader. OpenGl-ES 2.0 uses version 100

Comment: Could you please provide code of fragment shader too?

Comment: `#version 100` would be the correct statement for OpenGL ES 2.0, not 150. You could try that.

Comment: As you stated adding invalid directive caused the same error on PC too. As I see this, after shader fails to compile/link application fails to get 1st uniform of shader (it is `mvp`). You should check whether there are some shader compilation/linking errors - check GL error after each call to GL functions in process of creating shader. There should be some shader compilation error which is a main cause of this error.

Comment: @ArttuPeltonen - Unfortunatly it seems to have the same result as using 150, or any other number for that matter.

Comment: @keaukraine - Ahhhh, as it seems that it didnt like the version number because I forgot to put a newline after it. Once that was done and a few more compile errors fixed it loaded right up on the PC and Pi.


End result is that the problem was fixed using a combination of the number provided by ArttuPeltonen and the debugging from keaukraine. Thanks!

Comment: Great. You can answer your question explaining how you've fixed it and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by keaukraine and ArttuPeltonen

Raspberry Pi requires a version number in the shader. OpenGl-ES 2.0 uses version 100. It did not work when I initially tried it due to forgetting to add whitespace. "#version 100attribute..." is not the same as "#version 100\nattribute"

Example Final Shader:

```
Vertex_Shader = 
    "#version 100\n"
  + "attribute vec3 a_position; \n"
  + "attribute vec4 a_color; \n"
  + "attribute vec2 a_texCoords; \n"
  + "uniform mat4 mvp; \n"
  + "varying vec4 v_color; \n" + "varying vec2 tCoord; \n" 
  + "void main() { \n" 
  + "   v_color = a_color; \n"
  + "   tCoord = a_texCoords; \n"
  + "   gl_Position =  mvp * vec4(a_position, 1f);  \n"
  + "}";
```

Thank you both.

Comment: Causes of the hardest to find errors can be even more trivial than this. Glad too see you've found and fixed bug.